# JPA: do i have to fetch all OneToMany relation list in order to add new relation

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

lets say i have Entity A  and A Has List of B which is mark as OneToMany. do i have to fetch all of B items in order to add new B item to the list A has?

example:

```
@Entity
public class A {

   @Id
   Long id;

   @OneToMany
   List<B> bs;
}
```

do i have to fetch all of A.bs in order to add new item to bs ?

thanks

Alon

**EDIT**
few more questions:

@German: interesting!  few questions

1. what if the join between A and B is by Table C? do i get the same behavior?
2. why does the list make troubles?
3. what can i use instead of a list? Set?
4. if I persist A do i overwrite all the links for B?
5. what if the link is ManyToMany (using extra table)

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the b to A's bs list.  What happens though is provider specific.  Some providers like EclipseLink can avoid fetching the list for some operations on lazy loaded lists when change tracking is enabled

Answer (score 1):

If B has a @ManyToOne annotation pointing back to A and you will not use the list, you may only need to set B's reference to A and persist it, without needing to touch A instance at all. In the database the data will be inserted into table B, but in memory, A's list will not have the new element.